# gustil change part of all files names' in multiple folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rename

I have folder on GCS which contains 4 folders: 'fold1','fold2','fold3','fold4' .
each of these folders contains GeoTiff files, but accidently, I gave wrong prefix to all the files. All the images should end with '.tif' ,' but accidently I generated files ends with '.tif.tif' .
I want to change all the names of the files in all the folders, to have only '.tif' in the name.
For example,
Image name "basel.tif.tif" will be changed into "basel.tif" .

My first step was to create "test" folder for the naming by copying the original file:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://bucket/folders/more_folders/even_more_folders/here_4_folders gs://bucket/folders/more_folders/even_more_folders/here_4_folders_COPY
```

Than I have tried to rename it using the following command:

```
$ gsutil -m mv gs://bucket/folders/more_folders/even_more_folders/here_4_folders_COPY/**/*.tif.tif gs://bucket/folders/more_folders/even_more_folders/here_4_folders_COPY/**/\1.tif
```

but I get with this error:

> **CommandException: Destination (gs://bucket/folders/more_folders/even_more_folders/here_4_folders_COPY/**/\1.tif)
> must match exactly 1 URL**

I understand that I don't really "catch" the correct urls with this line, but not sure what is the mistake.
My gosl it to change names from 'name.tif.tif' to 'name.tif'

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to rename the file extensions on my environment, you can use the `gsutil mv` command + `sed` to place the file extension and rewrite the file as desired on your Cloud Shell or local machine

```
IFS=$'\n'
gsutil ls gs://bucket-name/folder/*.txt| while read x; do gsutil mv $x $(echo $x | sed "s/.txt/.doc/g"); done
```